# SD card reader suddenly read-only

Tags: usb, sd-card

I have a Macbook Air M1 With Mac OS Ventura 13.0.1.
I've been using an external SD card reader and it has always worked - until today.
Things i've tried:

- Multiple SD cards
- Multiple USB-A-To-C Adapters
- Rebooting
- Rebooting in Safe Mode
- Fiddling around with the Lock

I have now even used the sd card reader on a friend's macbook. That works.
The only thing I have changed between when it worked and now, is that I installed a USB-to-UART driver. More exactly CP210x VCP. Is it even possible that the driver interferes somehow? There is no other usb device connected.

Comment: Standard troubleshooting would dictate that the last change before the incorrect behavior is the cause (Occam's razor, of sorts) of your problem no matter how unlikely it seems. That doesn't mean that **is** the problem, merely the most likely.

Comment: I deleted the driver - to no avail. Bonus: i got a new sd card reader today, it works like a charm. The old one still doesn‘t. On my mac that is, on my friend‘s mac no problem.